# Can we alias a class name the way we do in namespaces?

Tags: c++

Can we  alias a class name the way we do in namespaces?

For example:

```
namespace longname{ }
namespace ln = longname;// namespace aliasing

class LONGNAME {};
class LN = LONGNAME; // how to do class name aliasing, if allowed?
```

Comment: `typedef` should do it, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simple:

```
typedef LONGNAME LN;
```

Typedefs are used in C++ a bit like "variables which can store types". Example:

```
class Car
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<Wheel> WheelCollection;

    WheelCollection wheels;
};
```

By using `Car::WheelCollection` everywhere instead of `std::vector<Wheel>`, you can change the container type in one place and have all your code reflect the changes. This is the C++ way to abstract data types (whereas eg. in C# you'd have a property returning `IEnumerable<Wheel>`).

Comment: When you posted that as an answer and not comment you should have shown a little more courtesy to explain at least the basics.

Comment: @Rohit: What basics ? Typedef is the simplest statement of C++, and there is nothing to know except having seen it once.

Comment: A little theory on how to use it. or what is a typedef, etc would be great answer

Comment: @Rohit: I added a typical use case.

Answer (score 21):

Beside the answers already provided using the keyword `typedef`, you also can use the keyword `using` since C++11. IMHO it looks more consistent regarding the aliasing.

```
namespace longname{ }
namespace ln = longname;// namespace aliasing

class LONGNAME {};
using LN = LONGNAME; // "class aliasing"
```

In addition, with `using` you are able to alias template classes ([How to typedef a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6907194/1810087)) by using [alias templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

```
template<typename T> class LONGNAME {};
template<typename T> using LN = LONGNAME<T>; // alias template
```

Comment: Effective modern C++ 2014, S. Meyers, Item 9

Comment: This is the right answer for c++11 on-words

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [typedef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) keyword:

```
typedef LONGNAME LN;
```

You can also do something like:

```
typedef class {

...

} LN;
```

**Edit:**
You may run into trouble when using templates though. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708593/alternative-to-template-declaration-of-typedef) for a possible solution.

Comment: The provided link is unrelated, as it deals with templates, not classes, and those are completely different beasts.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I just thought the OP also might be interesting in `typedef`ing template classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef int mark;  // for in built data types

class abc
{
};

typedef abc XYZ; // for user written classes.
```

Typedef allows you to alias a class or datatype name with a more context sensitive name corresponding to the scenario.