# Does C++ provide a way to access a class within a class without the scope resolution operator?

Tags: c++

Does C++ provide a way to declare an object that has the type of a class within a class (e.g. `foo_class::bar_class_in_class` in the example below) without having to use the scope resolution operator, as it does for a class within a namespace (e.g. `foo_namespace::bar_class_in_namespace` in example below)?

```
  namespace foo_namespace {
      class bar_class_in_namespace {
      };

  }

  class foo_class {
  public:
      class bar_class_in_class {
      };
  };


  int main() {
      using namespace foo_namespace;
      bar_class_in_namespace bar_0;

      // Can I access bar_class_in_class without having to use the
      // the scope resolution operator?
      foo_class::bar_class_in_class bar_1;
  }
```

This question is the same as [Can we alias a class name the way we do in namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791239/can-we-alias-a-class-name-the-way-we-do-in-namespaces), with the minor difference that this question asks explicitly about a class within a class.

Comment: Related: [Can we alias a class name the way we do in namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791239/can-we-alias-a-class-name-the-way-we-do-in-namespaces)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, C++ offers a way to access the type.  What you need is a type alias.  Using

```
using bar_class_in_class = foo_class::bar_class_in_class;
```

allows you to use `bar_class_in_class` in place of `foo_class::bar_class_in_class`.  This is scoped so if you do it in `main`, you can only see the alias in `main`

---

Do note that you can also "change the name" of the inner type

```
using my_type = foo_class::bar_class_in_class;
```

does the same thing as above, but you would use `my_type` as the type name.  This can be a nice convenience.

Comment: Note that alias might have other name that inner type.